# Using SPContext.Current to get public URL of the current zone

Tags: 2007, alternate-access-mapping, spweb, web-application-zones

I have a single content Web application in the Default zone of my MOSS 2007 farm, which I then extended to the Extranet zone. The default zone web application uses Windows authentication and standard HTTP, while the extranet zone uses forms authentication and SSL. I have the following alternate access mappings configured:

```
Internal URL            Zone      Public URL for Zone
--------------          -------   ------------------------
http://server1          Default   http://server1
https://www.server.com  Extranet  https://www.server.com
http://www.server.com   Extranet  https://www.server.com
```

Now I'm certainly not an AAM expert, so let me know if any of those seems wrong from the outset. The problem I'm having is, when I access my site using `https://www.server.com`, I'm finding that `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` returns `http://server1`. I was expecting `https://www.server.com`, instead.

So, did I miss something or are my expectations out of line?

Answer (score 2):

you could try the following:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Zone, SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review the [answer from a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716799/getting-public-internet-url-for-the-sharepoint-portal-site) using the `SPSite.MakeFullUrl` method as well:

```
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite(currentSiteId, SPUrlZone.Default) 
{ 
    string publicUrl = site.MakeFullUrl(serverRelativeUrl); 
    // note that MakeFullUrl takes a server relative url not a site relative one 
}
```