# Workflow: Current Item Url

Tags: workflow, alternate-access-mapping

I have a site set up with a workflow that sends mail with a link to a task. We use alternate access mappings in order to access this site across the company.

My issue is that in my workflow, %Workflow Context:Current Item URL% points to the machine name and not the dns name. How do we resolve this issue?

My table of access mappings looks a bit like this:

```
http://acme-spf2010:7070      Default   http://acme-spf2010:7070
http://eno.acmegroup.net      Intranet  http://eno.acmegroup.net
http://eno.acmegroup.net:7070 Internet  http://eno.acmegroup.net:7070
```

Comment: Do u have host header for your site in IIS ?

Comment: Yes I do. Both blank and eno.acmegroup.net. Why?

Comment: It seems that this is alternate access mapping configuration problem (or dns?), because for me list item url resolved correctly on virtual machine. `acme-spf2010` is a machine name?

Comment: Check out http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/using-spcontext-current-to-get-public-url-of-the-current-zone, you can get the address for the correct zone.

Comment: @DavidLozzi,I am afraid this issue in sharepoint designer workflow....

Comment: How are you creating that workflow? In SPD? If so, are you connecting to it using the internet URL?

Comment: Solved! It turns out that Sharepoint Workflows uses the default zone url.